# function overload and calling

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class X, class Y>
class A:
{
public:
  X r;
  Y s;
  A() { cout << "hi" << endl; }
  A(X r, Y s) { cout << r << " " << s << endl; }
};
int main()
{
  int val1 = 0;
  float val2 = 0;
  char c;
  cin >> val1;
  cin >> val2;
  cin >> c;
  A<char> a;
  A<int, char>(val1, c);
  A<char, float>(c, val2);
  return 0;
}
```

The code won't compiled because the line `A<char> a;` has too few arguments.

I want to execute the `A()` function in the class but it seems to always think it needs more argumenst. Can someone advice me why?

Comment: How many type parameters does your template take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have setup your template now you always have to specify to types, `X` and `Y`. If you specify the second template with a default you could call it with just the first while the code would assume the second to be the default:

```cpp
template <class X, class Y = char>
```

In this case the default is `char`.

Comment: awesome. quick question so when i set the second template to be the default as char. I tried the code with A <int, float> (num1, num2) as one of the lines. This still works for some reason even when the second template is default at char. why is that?

Comment: Because in that case you do not use the default but the new type you have set to float.

Answer (score 0):

Template takes exactly two paramateres, maybe you meant

```
A<char, char> a;
```

Note you can default-assign parameter types, to avoid this.
Those lines miss name of varaible for instances of A.

```
A<int, char>(val1, c);
A<char, float>(c, val2);
```

Comment: The two last lines create temporaries. They don't _need_ a variable name.